# DropDownListFor selected value returns null in the Enum property Model on form POST in ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, enums, asp.net-core-mvc, enumeration, dropdownlistfor

```
I have a form page with DropDownlistFor or select as below:

<select asp-for="LeaveType" 
         class="form-control" style="max-width:180px" 

         asp-items="@Html.GetEnumOcp_SelectList<LeaveType>(LeaveType.List, null)">

         <option selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>
 </select>
```

I have a viewModel with following property:

`public LeaveType LeaveType { get; set; }`

this is my enum model:

```
public class LeaveType(int value, string name) : Enumeration<LeaveType>(value, name)
{
    public static readonly LeaveType AnnualLeave = new(1, "AnnualLeave");
    public static readonly LeaveType SickLeave = new(2, "SickLeave");
    public static readonly LeaveType CompassionateLeave = new(3, "CompassionateLeave");
    public static readonly LeaveType UnpaidLeave = new(4, "UnpaidLeave");
}
```

I have htmlExtension :

```
public static SelectList GetEnumOcp_SelectList<TEnum>(this IHtmlHelper html,
        IReadOnlyCollection<TEnum> isValueUsedForValue, TEnum? selectedValue)
        where TEnum : LeaveType
    {
        var myList = isValueUsedForValue.Select(eachValue => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = eachValue.Text,
            Value = eachValue.Value.ToString(),
            Selected = eachValue.Equals(selectedValue)

        }).ToList();

        return new SelectList(myList, "Value", "Text");        
    }
```

in Index HttpGet action, I have expected LeaveTypes values but
When I do post my from (ViewModel) with DropDownList or Select to the controller I have all values except LeaveType property value which is null. Just be aware my enum (LeaveType) is not a struct type that is class.

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            Logger.LogInformation("Leave Index started");

            // Populate the form on the first visit
            var model = new LeaveViewModel(); // You can initialize with any default data if needed
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(LeaveViewModel model)
        {
            if (model == null) return NotFound();
            
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }     
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

Anyone know why LeaveType property get Null value when I submit the ViewModel to index post action. all fields values have passed successfully except **LeaveType**.
Thanks

Comment: Can you add Index [HttpGet] Controller please?

Comment: I have added  [HttpGet] Index action

Comment: Try to add a string type  property in your viewModel to bind the DropDownListFor selected value: `public string LeaveType { get; set; }`

Comment: My view model has already property with this name I want to use existed one not changing it with string data type.

public LeaveType LeaveType { get; set; }

Comment: I like to keep my existed one property  as a below image in my viewmodel

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5JSn.png

Answer (score 0):

Try returning them as a **SelectList**

```
public static SelectList GetEnumOcp_SelectList<TEnum>(this IHtmlHelper html,
    IReadOnlyCollection<TEnum> isValueUsedForValue, TEnum? selectedValue)
    where TEnum : LeaveType
{
    var myList = isValueUsedForValue.Select(eachValue => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = eachValue.Name,
        Value = eachValue.Value.ToString(),
        Selected = eachValue.Equals(selectedValue)

    }).ToList(); 

    return New SelectList(myList, "Value", "Text");

}
```

Comment: Nothing changes. The problem is not here. The problem is in ViewModel Property which is not binding  select tag with that  property model : 
`<select id="LeaveType" name="LeaveType">
                <option selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>
            <option value="1">AnnualLeave</option>
<option value="2">SickLeave</option>
<option value="3">CompassionateLeave</option>
<option value="4">UnpaidLeave</option>
</select>`

Comment: Nothing changed. It still is null after post request.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a work demo based on your code, you can refer to it.

Add a `string` type property in LeaveViewModel to bind selected value(if selected value is `int` type, you need to set the `int LeaveType`), as the select value based on  your comment code is string ,I  set `string LeaveType`:

```
public class LeaveViewModel
 {
     public string LeaveType { get; set; }
 }
```

the select:

```
<select id="LeaveType" name="LeaveType">                 
    <option selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>          
    <option value="1">AnnualLeave</option>
    <option value="2">SickLeave</option> 
    <option value="3">CompassionateLeave</option> 
    <option value="4">UnpaidLeave</option> </select>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have already the property with same name.  I need to find out solution to not duplicate porperty.


`
public class LeaveViewModel
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public LeaveType LeaveType { get; set; }    
}
`

Comment: I already I have a property with the same name.  I am happy to keep the data type of current property "LeaveType enum class". not change to string or adding new property with string.
public class LeaveViewModel
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public LeaveType LeaveType { get; set; }    
}

Comment: Hi @hms, the selected value type can be int or string, it cannot bind to the  type LeaveType enum. That's way is the simplest way to solve the problem. If you want to bind selected value to LeaveType enum, you need do a lot of works.

Comment: Hi @Qing Thank you for your help. My question is why when we use Enum EnumProperty it works with no neccessary adding or changing the current one to string property. our select item binding directly with Enum property, but it does not work with object class property. I am gonna say it works nicely with struct enum but not with class enum.

Answer (score 0):

```
•   Create datatype enum and add value
     public enum AnyName{
    data1,
    data2,
    data3
       }        
•   And than create class  by using enum data type
public class YourModel
{
    public AnyName   EnumProperty { get; set; }
}
•   Use enum value in  dropdown according this 
<select name="EnumProperty">
    <option value="data1">data1</option>
    <option value="data2">data2</option>
    <option value="data3">3</option>
</select>

•   And save data in database in controller by using post method 
               [HttpPost]
public IActionResult  YourAction(YourModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Process the model
        return RedirectToAction("Success");
    }
    // If ModelState is not valid, return the view with errors
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Please don't use code format (indented text) for everything, only for code. Or better: [use code fences](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).